# azure webapp deployment from local git fails but returns exit code 0

Tags: deployment, azure-web-app-service, bitbucket-pipelines

I use bitbucket pipelines to push code to an azure webapp (the webapp has "local git" setup as the deployment source).

I sometimes have the case that the bitbucket pipeline shows success even though the azure deployment failed. This seems to happen because the azure deployment returns exit code 0 even though it encountered an exception. Is there some config that allows to forward the actual exit code?

This is an example of the azure deployment log:

```
remote:                                                                                        
remote:   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'reports          
remote:   _user_id_foreign'; check that column/key exists                                      
remote:                                                                                        
remote: 
remote: Script @php artisan migrate handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1        
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.        
remote: 
remote: Deployment Failed.        
remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment to website failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your deployment issue is tied to your SQL error you're getting. It appears that you're doing a database migration during deployment against existing data. I would suggest doing database migrations as a separate pipeline so you can have more granular control.

Also, you mentioned

> the webapp has "local git" setup as the deployment source

Is there any reason why you didn't [configure the deployment source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment?tabs=bitbucket#configure-the-deployment-source) as your BitBucket repo?

Comment: I am doing some additional steps during deployment and only when they pass I want the bitbucket repo to be propagated to azure. That's why I took the local git approach.
The error being caused by a migration itself does not really matter. This problem also happens when any other exception is thrown. I would just like that the git push step fails if there is an error on the azure side.

Comment: What does your yaml pipeline look like? Have you tried having [Bitbucket deploy the artifacts](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/azure-web-apps-deploy/src/master/README.md)?